# MongoDB group records embedded an array by an attribute outside it

Tags: arrays, mongodb, grouping

What I want from the below data is to ***group by customer_unique_id and*** get both the ***total number of orders*** that each customer did: `{$group: {_id: "$customer_unique_id", tot_ords{$sum: 1}}` and ALSO how much each customer spends in total (considering that ***each order_payments array can contains more payments*** for the same order). In other words I want ***both the sum of different payment_value in the same orders and than the sum of all these payment_value for each customer***.

```
{'order_id': '00e7ee1b050b8499577073aeb2a297a1',
 'customer_unique_id': '861eff4711a542e4b93843c6dd7febb0',
 'order_payments': [{'payment_type': 'credit_card',
'payment_installments': 2.0,'payment_value': 150}]},


{'order_id': 'b2059ed67ce144a36e2aa97d2c9e9ad2',
 'customer_unique_id': '060e732b5b29e8181a18229c7b0b2b5e',
 'order_payments': [{'payment_type': 'credit_card',
   'payment_installments': 7.0,
   'payment_value': 100}, {'payment_type': 'credit_card',
   'payment_installments': 1.0,
   'payment_value': 30.00}]}

{'order_id': '00e7ee1b050b8499577073ceb5a297a1',
 'customer_unique_id': '861eff4711a542e4b93843c6dd7febb0',
 'order_payments': [{'payment_type': 'credit_card',
'payment_installments': 10.0,'payment_value': 1000}]},

{'order_id': 'b2059ed67ce188a36e2aa97d2c9e9ad2',
 'customer_unique_id': '060e732b5b29e8181a18229c7b0b2b5e',
 'order_payments': [{'payment_type': 'credit_card',
   'payment_installments': 7.0,
   'payment_value': 80}]}
```

RESULT:

```
{
 'customer_unique_id': '060e732b5b29e8181a18229c7b0b2b5e',
'tot_purchases': 2,
'tot_spendings': 1150},

{
 'customer_unique_id': '060e732b5b29e8181a18229c7b0b2b5e',
'tot_purchases': 2,
'tot_spendings': 210},
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
ords_col.aggregate([
    {'$group': {'_id': "$customer_unique_id", 'tot_purchases': {'$sum': 1}, 'order_payments': {'$push': '$order_payments'}}},
    {'$project': {"_id": 0, 'customer_unique_id': '$_id', 
        'tot_purchases': '$tot_purchases', 'order_payments': {'$reduce':{'input': '$order_payments',
        'initialValue': [], 'in': {'$concatArrays':['$$value', '$$this']}}}}},
    {'$unwind': '$order_payments'},
    {'$group': {'_id': "$customer_unique_id", 'tot_spendings':{'$sum': '$order_payments.payment_value'}, 'tot_purchases':{'$first': '$tot_purchases'}}},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'customer_unique_id': '$_id', 'tot_purchases': '$tot_purchases', 'tot_spendings': '$tot_spendings'}},
    {'$sort': {"tot_purchases": -1}}
    ])
```

Is it possible directly sum the order_payments values in each dictionary in each array directly in the reduce? I mean: instead of flat the array and then group, directly in the reduce flat the array and group for specific value of records in it.